# Disabling Text Field in install4j

Tags: install4j

[image]

Hi colleagues! My installer has following screen.
I need enable 'HTTP' and 'HTTPS' fields only if 'Need proxy configuration was selected' otherwise they should be disabled.
I prepared some code fragment:

```
if (!context.getBooleanVariable("isProxyNeed")) {
    context.getInstallationComponentById("httpInput").setEnabled(false);
}
```

But I don't understand when can I it use ?

Answer (score 0):

For that use case, do not use the "Radio button group" form component, but two instances of the "Single radio button" form component.

The "Single radio button" form component has a "Coupled Form Components" configuration where you can select the form components that should only be enabled when the radio button is selected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Another little question. Can I specify some mask for Text Input ? For example I need input only for numbers.

Comment: That's a different form component, the "Text field with integer format" form component

Comment: But there is huge minus in the following approach. You can select all radio buttons in the same time.

Comment: No, you have to bind them to the same variable name, then they form a radio button group and only one can be selected.